# WP; get_sidebar not playing nice with get_content when inside loop querying pages

Tags: php, while-loop, wordpress

So I hope that title isn't too confusing, let me try to break it down.

I have a content-page.php file which has both the get_content and get_sidebar functions in it. If I navigate to that page on the front end, I see both my content and sidebar.

On the home.php page, I'm loading a series of **pages** by using $the_query = new WP_Query and then inside that query using the loop and inside that loop, calling the content-page.php.

The problem is that if the page that loads on the home.php page has a sidebar, for some reason, nothing loads after the sidebar ie. `get_content()` returns nothing, `comments_template()` returns nothing, etc.

Here's a (very) simplified version of the markup, Homepage:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'page'));
    $x = 0;
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        $the_query->the_post();

        get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

    $x++;
    endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
```

content-page.php:

```
<article <?php post_class(); ?>>  
    <header>
      <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </header>

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/sidebar.php'); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

sidebar.php:

```
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
    <?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' );
    dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
</div><!-- #secondary .widget-area -->
```

Is there something obvious that I'm missing here? Been working on this one for a while. As always, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your issue... You say the problem is that if the page that loads on the home.php page has a sidebar, for some reason, nothing loads after the sidebar ie. get_content() returns nothing, comments_template() returns nothing, etc." What do you mean? The content returned from a loop would not contain a sidebar. The sidebar would be part of a page-template, and generally wouldn't be associated with any post's content.

Comment: Hi Jim, that's exactly right. Here's why I'm loading the sidebar in the loop. This is a theme I'm creating in where I'm giving the user the option to select which sidebar they want to display on each page / post specifically. So the can have the 1st registered sidebar display on page-x and the 2nd display on page-y. This all works great when you just go the page. But if I loop through all the pages on the home page using `WP_Query` to filter only pages, number of pages, etc., calling the sidebar seem to stop other functions from loading - ie.` get_content()`

Comment: Well I think you just answered your own question! Wordpress is not designed to call the sidebar multiple times from within the loop.

Comment: Hmmm, seems to be a feature that is pretty standard in many commercial wp themes. That's not to say I'm doing it correctly, as clearly I'm not, but that is to say that the desired result is possible.

Comment: Anything is possible! I was just pointing out that it's not a standard Wordpress feature. You're basically going to have to create your own sidebar system to do this.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, I'm starting to think that themes that have this feature, are just not calling a series of pages to the homepage. As I mentioned in the question, it works fine on the individual pages, just not through the `WP_query` filter. If you want to explain that it can't be done in an answer, I'll accept it and reward the bounty. cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of general Loop queries in WordPress:

1. the main query, which is set based on the HTTP request, and
2. 'sub loops' which can change the main query.

Since the main query controls many things like "is there a sidebar?" or "what page template should be used?" you can only submit one of these types. You can't call a separate sidebar (or call a separate page template for that matter) from within a sub loop. To do this, you would have to re-do the basic WordPress sidebar system.

I think the best bet for what you are trying to do, would be to just serve up some kind of dynamic content and call it a sidebar. In other words, WordPress has already decided what's happening with the sidebar the first time it was called. The system doesn't have a default way to handle calling the sidebar over and over. Using a shortcode or a filter after each iteration of the sub loop would be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Close ")" open brackets.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page') );
```

Comment: ok, can you change the name of your page Home.php to some other because its default use for post list in wordpress so once check by changing name of page.

Comment: That did have an affect, but not the desired one. Now, if there are no posts, everything shows up correctly for the first page shown on home (front.php), but the sidebars don't fire on the following ones. If there are posts, none of the content shows up for the first page shown on home (front.php), just the sidebar.

Comment: In other words, the content is being called each time, but the sidebar is only being called for the first instance in the loop.

Comment: So I've figured out how to get the sidebar to fire each time - not sure why this is, but you have to use `include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/sidebar.php');` instead of `get_sidebar()`. The page `the_content` still won't fire if there are published posts though.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code in content-page.php

```
<?php get_template_part( 'sidebar' ); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
```

Try removing `do_action( 'before_sidebar' );`

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no difference when I make that edit, Prakash.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

`include( locate_template( 'content-page.php', false, false ) );`

instead of:

`get_template_part('content', 'page');`

Comment: Cheers, fostertime, unfortunately, that did not result in any changes.

Comment: @EricBrockman hmm, so the `post_class();` and `the_title();` are loading properly. It's just `the_content();` that isn't loading at this point? If `the_content();` is located directly in the `while` statement, does it load without fail?

Comment: So I added this code to a dev project I have, and everything works perfectly. Couple questions... 1) is your `content-page.php` in the root of your project, or is it in a sub-directory? Mine is located at `template-parts/content`. 2) is there a specific reason you're adding the `do_action` before the sidebar call?

Comment: It operates the same. Basically, if I don't call the sidebar from inside the loop it works fine, regardless if it's directly in the loop or being called from a different file. In this scenario the sidebar needs to be called from within the loop though, because the home page is set to display x amount of pages, and each one of those pages has the option to select and add sidebars using a metabox function from the page editing page on the backend.

Comment: `content-page.php` is added to the root of the theme. As for the `do_action`, it's one of those things I read years a go was good practice, and have included it in every theme since. Removing it does not make a difference though.

Comment: That is really strange... only because this is working perfectly in my dev site. I get 8 pages printed out with sidebars and content... Do you have custom sidebar widgets getting inserted on that sidebar?

Comment: That is weird. Just to be clear, you're using `$the_query = new WP_Query` to call pages (not posts), and your calling the sidebar and then the content from within the loop?

Comment: I general sidebar widgets being called into each sidebar from the widget page, yes.

Comment: I cut and pasted your code into my template. Everything is exactly the same. And I get all pages and sidebars.